# Image Update is not happening in Django

Tags: python, django

I had used code to update the image in Django, but it doesn't resulted as expected.

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = ImageModel.objects.get(pk=id)
        pid = customer.objects.get(pk=id)
        fm = CustomerRegisteration(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=pid)
        if fm.is_valid():
            data.image_document.delete()
            fm.save()
```

This code doesn't work

Comment: `data.save()`...

Comment: Lemme try this one.

Comment: getting a new error in browser of {"name 'ImageModel' is not defined"}

Comment: In the HTML you need define the ImageField correctly.